# Is a MySQL SELECT query slower if a table has lots of other data?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Suppose I have two tables (with the same amount of rows). The first one only has one column, say `ID`. The second one has the same column plus an additional one, say `Text` (of type `longtext`) which may contain a lot of data.

Now consider a query of the form `SELECT ID FROM table WHERE ID>=7`.

**Question**: Is this query slower on the second table then on the first one? The query does not use the `Text` column, but maybe this data still affects the performance of the query.

Comment: Is there an index on `ID` field? Are you dealing with millions of rows or more?

Comment: The real table I'm using has lots of rows, but not millions of them. ID is primary, but my question is if there is a (significant) decrease in performance for queries which do not reference these data-intensive columns, compared to the same table without these (non-referenced) columns.

Comment: If `ID` is a Primary Key - then times in both cases should be practically the same.

Comment: @PM77-1 Backward. If `id` is indexed but is not PK then the time will be the same. But if it is PK then it is clustered, and the difference matches the difference in row size approximately.

Comment: @Akina - Are you talking about a difference in a page read speed?

Comment: @PM77-1 I talk about the pages amount which must be read from disk.

Answer (score 1):

In this simple query the most part of the query execution time is a time needed for reading the data from disk, and total time is approximately equal to disk reading time.

Case 1. The column is not indexed in both tables.

The server should scan (and hence should read) the whole table for to find the rows matched the condition. In this case the time needed for the query execution is approximately proportional to the disk size occupied by the table.

Case 2. The column is clustered index expression in both tables.

This can be when this column is the only column in the primary key expression or, if the primary key is not defined, when this column is the only column in the unique key expression, this unique key is the most first index defined in the table structure (physically in CREATE TABLE code), and this column is defined as NOT NULL.

The server should read the table part starting from the block which contains the row with first value matched the condition for to find the rows matched this condition. The time needed for the query execution is approximately proportional to the disk size occupied by the table part to be read, so it is approximately proportional to the disk size occupied by the whole table. But when the table on-disk body pages contains too many "empty" elements (deleted rows) then the difference is unpredictable.

Case 3. The column is indexed as secondary index in both tables.

In this case the index is separate on-disk structure, and the server will read this index only. When the index expressions are equal, and the datatypes are equal too, then the disk sizes occupied by these indexes are approximately equal too. And the time needed for both queries execution will be approximately the same.

Case 4. In one table this column is clustered index expression and in another table it is secondary index expression.

The disk size needed for secondary index is less than the disk size needed for clustered index. So the query to the table in which this column is secondary index will be faster.

Comment: This is the best answer on this thread so far. I would add that Case 1 is specific to MySQL (and so-called "row-store" databases in general). Many new-generation databases such as Google BigQuery, Amazon Redshift, Snowflake, etc. are column-store (a.k.a "analytical"), and are designed to only read data from the columns you're selecting from

Answer (score 0):

(My "cases" are different than Akina's)

Assuming (Please add to the Question):

- `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY` on each table.
- Both tables are InnoDB.

Let's look at the structure of each:

- The id-only table is a long list of ids in a B+Tree.  Aside from InnoDB overhead, there is nothing extra.
- Each row in the other table has two things (plus overhead):  `id`, and *either* the text value (if short enough) or a "pointer" to an "off-record" place containing the text.  (The cutoff depends on `ROW_FORMAT`, MySQL version, and the phase of the moon.  Note that each row, therefore, is bulkier than the id-only table, but id tricky to predict how much bulkier.

Conclusion 1:  The `SELECT id FROM with_text` will need to read more blocks because of the text column.  The number of blocks for the second table is likely to be twice as many, even without fetching the text.

We need more assumptions before we can launch into answering the question:

- Will the data (excluding the off-record parts) fit in the buffer_pool?  If not, there will be a lot of I/O.
- Is this the first run of your 'query'?  If the data will fit into the buffer pool, the *first* time you run it, it will be slow; subsequent times will have no I/O, hence be faster.
- Will the rows be inserted in primary-key order?  "In order" will be up to twice as densely packed.
- There are no secondary indexes.  If there were, the `SELECT id ...` might use the index instead.  That would mess up the block count, hence speed.

Conclusion 2:  Nothing is trivial.

I spelled out details so that you would hesitate to apply the conclusions to some other pair of tables.

In particular, `INDEX(foo)` is like the `SELECT id FROM without_text` case.

Answer (score -1):

To echo "PM-77's" reply:  if `ID` is a primary key, then it necessarily has an (implicit ...) *index.*  The query will make use of this index.

Therefore, any other (irrelevant) structural differences *will not* affect the performance of the query.

Comment: Exactly what I just said:  **the primary-key is always "indexed."**  No, it does not appear as a separate "index."  Therefore, when retrieving any row by its primary key, the SQL engine will always use this *implicit* index.